# Regex replace depending on the match

Tags: c#, regex, pos-tagger

I am working on some POS-tagger analysis and i need to replace some tags.
I am using a regular expression to identify the tags:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/(?<firstMatch>[^\s]+)( )");
```

//anything between "/" and " ", sample tags: /NN, /VB, etc...

Now, i am getting the tag name into firstMatch group, so i can access them like

```
foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(allText))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["firstMatch"].Value);
}
```

What i want to do is to replace the tag name with some other tag, depending on it's name.
Like, if the tag name is DTI i want to replace it with DT. If it's NNS, i want to replace it with NN. And so on, from a list of tags that i have. Can i do that?
I was thinking if there is a match-replace so i can use in that for.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this Regex.Replace method with MatchEvaluator will be useful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx

Comment: your last example contradicts your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string,string> tags = new Dictionary<string,string>();

public string UpadeInput(String input)
{
    tags.Add("DTI", "DT");
    tags.Add("NNS", "NN");
    tags.Add("LongAnnoyingTag", "ShortTag");
    MatchEvaluator evaluator = new MatchEvaluator(ModifyTag);
    return Regex.Replace(input,@"(?<=/)(?<firstMatch>[^\s]+)(?= )", evaluator);
}

public string ModifyTag(Match match)
{
    return tags[match.Value];
}
```

**Edit** for composed tag.

You can just change the `ModifyTag` method to work with different cases.

```
public string ModifyTag(Match match)
{
    String tag = match.Value;
    if(!tag.Contains("+"))
    {
        return tags[match.Value];
    }
    else
    {
        string[] composedTags = tag.Split('+');
        return String.Format("{0}+{1}", tags[composedTags[0]], tags[composedTags[1]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry! I will try it soon enough and be back with a feedback.

Comment: It's exactly what i needed! Thank you Dmitry. But i can see match.Value keeps the firstMatch group. What if i have 2 groups?

Comment: If i have, let's say, a composed tag. Like /NNS+DTI which should be replaced with /NN+DT. I have made a regular expression like this: "(?<=/)(?<firstMatch>[^\s]+)\+(?<secondMatch>[^\s]+)(?= )". Is it possible to check each match? (the composition can only have 2 tags, no more. /tag1+tag2

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question

```
Regex.Replace(input,"/(?<firstMatch>[^\s]+)[^\s](?= )","$1");
```

This would replace the tag name with the same tag name except last character..